# How to remove all sublists from a list?

Tags: python, list, sublist

How do I remove all 'sublists' from a list in Python 3 i.e turn a list containing other lists into one giant list?

For example say I have:

`myList = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]`

How do I turn this into:

`[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`?

Thanks.

Comment: `[x for l in myList for x in l]`

Answer (score 1):

Use [itertools.chain.from_iterable](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
from itertools import chain

myList = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

print(list(chain.from_iterable(myList)))
```

This prints:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

without using `.from_iterables` you can just unpack the list.

```
print(list(chain(*myList))
```

This does the same thing